# Resigning a text view as first responder and making a text field first responder when pressing return

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app with a text view and a text field where the user inputs a question in the view and an answer in the field. I want it to resign the view as first responder when the user presses return and make the field first responder and I tried the code below but it doesn't seem to be working and I can't figure out why

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if text=="\n"{
        questionTV.resignFirstResponder()
        answerTF.becomeFirstResponder()
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried the following code:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        guard text == "\n" else { return true }

        textView.resignFirstResponder()
        textField.becomeFirstResponder()

        return false
    }
```

It works as expected.

I guess, the reason might be somewhere else. Do you have any more details to share?

Did you set text view's delegate? Do you stop at breakpoint inside `shouldChangeTextIn` method?

**UPDATE:**

In comments it came clear that you conformed to the wrong protocol. You need to conform to `UITextViewDelegate` instead of `UITextFieldDelegate`. You might want to keep `UITextFieldDelegate` conformance, if you need it for work with text field though.

Comment: ```questionTV.delegate=self as? UITextViewDelegate ``` is the delegate

Comment: Why is `as? UITextViewDelegate` needed?

Comment: It gives me the error "Cannot assign value of type 'AddViewController' to type 'UITextViewDelegate?'"

Comment: It means that `AddViewController` does not conform to `UITextViewDelegate`, which in tern means that delegate is set to nil, which in turn means that you `shouldChangeTextIn` method is not called.

Comment: I have ```class AddViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{...``` is there anything else I need to do to conform?

Comment: Yes, you conformed to `UITextFieldDelegate` while you needed to conform to `UITextViewDelegate`.